# Defining specific fill colours on barcharts in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, colors, bar-chart, palette

I have a barchart using a palette in R but want to manually define my own colours so match the study groups in other software. I'd like Controls to be green and B - Treated to be blue. These are my 2 Study.Groups.

Current code:

```
E <- ggplot(diane2, aes(x = factor(Wavenumber), y = Absorbance, fill = Study.Group))   
  + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", bin_width=50)  
G <- E + labs(title = "Figure 1. Controls versus Normal Treated B's", x = "Wavenumber", y = "Absorbance (a.u.)")  
G + guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth =2, keyheight = 1, reverse = TRUE))  
G + scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

Comment: `?scale_fill_manual`

Comment: @BenBolker. Thank you. I've tried that but it changes the line of the bar plot but not the area.

Comment: are you sure you're not confusing `scale_colour_manual` and `scale_fill_manual` ?  If you're still having problems, could you please edit to provide a reproducible example?

Comment: E <- ggplot(diane2, aes(x = factor(Wavenumber), y = Absorbance, fill = Study.Group)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", bin_width=50)
G <- E + labs(title = "Figure 1. Controls versus Normal Treated B's", x = "Wavenumber", y = "Absorbance (a.u.)")
G + guides(fill = guide_legend(keywidth =2, keyheight = 1, reverse = TRUE))
G + scale_fill_manual(values=c("green","blue"))

Comment: (1) that's not [reproducible](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) (we need your data, or you need to give us a similar small data set); (2) can you *edit your question* to provide the example rather than giving it in comments?

Comment: @BenBolker. It's okay. you're advice was sound. I used the 'fill' instead and it worked. Example above is just to evidence it. Thank you.